# Uncaught exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'xx\xxxx\xxx does not exist' in

Tags: php, symfony, restful-authentication, silex

So I was using [silex](/questions/tagged/silex) and was refering to documentation.
So when I tried to implement the `SecurityServiceProvider` I encountered this message.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\ContextListener does not exist' in
```

This got me pulling my hairs long enough to come and post here, on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is mainly generated because of, the dependency not being required.

In simple language, the code for this function "doesn't exist" in your code base, so you have to run the `composer` command to `require` the respective package, once composer downloads and installs the needed files you should be good to go.

So in my case I had to run the following composer command.

```
composer require symfony/security
```